# CDhtmlDialog: How to capture event from iframe?

Tags: windows, mfc, webbrowser-control

I have a CHtmlDialog with an iframe in it.  I can capture onClick event from the button placed in the top level HTML with DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK macro.  But the same method doesn't work with the event from the button placed in the iframe.  Is there a way to capture events from iframe?

(By the way, both pages come from resource and they don't have cross-domain policy problem.)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of a proper solution for this.

The only way I can think of to get this to work is to ping a web endpoint from the iframe using a session id along with event/parameter data and poll that service using the session id from the app.

I'm looking into hosting a local web server within the app to facilitate this.

**Edit - My implementation.**

The workaround I found was to have the iFrame make a fake network request with attribute data attached as url parameters. I then listen on a thread to the local DNS cache for requests to the fake domain and extract the name value parameters.

Here is a snippet that reads the DNS cache:

```
UINT CIFrameListener::ListenerThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
    THREADPARAM* ts = (THREADPARAM*)pParam;
    Util util;
    long startScanTime = util.TimeMS();

    HINSTANCE dnsApiLib = LoadLibraryA("DNSAPI.dll");
    DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE dnsGetCacheDataTable = nullptr;
    if(dnsApiLib != nullptr) {
        dnsGetCacheDataTable = (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)GetProcAddress(dnsApiLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");
    }

    while(ts->_this->m_running){
        int dnsIndex = 0;
        // Check DNS 
        DNSCACHEENTRY entry;
        PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = &entry;
        dnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry);
        pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
        while(pEntry != nullptr) {
            size_t len = wcslen(pEntry->pszName);
            CString domain(pEntry->pszName);
            bool allreadyProcessed = false;
            for (int i=0; i<ts->_this->messagesSent.size(); i++){
                if( domain.Compare(ts->_this->messagesSent[i]) == 0){
                    allreadyProcessed = true;
                }
            }
            ts->_this->messagesSent.push_back(domain);
            if(allreadyProcessed == false){
                int end = domain.Find(_T(".infocache.fakedomain.com"));
                if(end != -1){
                    TRACE2(" Domain: %s  %d \n", domain, dnsIndex);
                    int pos = domain.ReverseFind('-'); 
                    if(pos != -1){
                        CString token3 = domain.Mid(pos + 1, end - pos - 1);
                        domain = domain.Mid(0, pos);
                        pos = domain.ReverseFind('-'); 
                        if(pos != -1){
                            CString token2 = domain.Mid(pos + 1, domain.GetLength() - pos - 1);
                            domain = domain.Mid(0, pos);

                            pos = domain.ReverseFind('-');
                            if(pos != -1){
                                CString token1 = domain.Mid(pos + 1, domain.GetLength() - pos - 1);
                                CString token0 = domain.Mid(0, pos);
                                int comp = ts->_this->m_session.Compare(token0);
                                if(comp == 0){
                                    // Notify handler there is a new event.
                                    // notify(token2, token3, token0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dnsIndex++;
                }
            }
            pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
        }
        Sleep(250);
    }
    return 1;
}
```